# Run Program and wait for process to complete

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have a simple BAT sdcript that should run the WTVCnverter. I want it to match all files by *.wtv and using the program convert to dvr-ms. Before executing the second or third file it should wait for the WTVConverter to exit before proceeding.

```
 @echo off


 for %%f in (*.in) do (

      echo %%~nf
      C:\Windows\ehome\WTVConverter.exe "%%~nf.wtv""%%~nf.dvr-ms" /ShowUI | out-null

 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a batch file (though your code works as is if typed) preface the command with `cmd /c start "" /w` so

```
cmd /c start "" /w C:\Windows\ehome\WTVConverter.exe "%%~nf.wtv""%%~nf.dvr-ms" /ShowUI | out-null
```

GUI processes (ie not console) are waited on in batch but not when typed. See `start /?`.

Pipes are also implemented by cmd.exe. If your pipe character is for your program escape with a `^`.

You seem to be lacking a space between in and out filename.